# Android background thread continually listening to an UDP port

Tags: java, android

I really appreciate that you take a couple of minutes to read my problem, thanks in advance!

I am building a non-public app for some specific users and here is my problem:

---

I have a service for background workloads in which I started a user thread that continually listens to an UDP port. It works fine when the device screen is turned on but lost all UDP packets when screen turned off.

Following is what I wrote in the thread:

```
// Android os v7.1.2, wifi 
DatagramSocket s;
DatagramPacket p;  // already initialized 
while (true) {
    try {
        if (s == null || !s.isBound()) {
            s = new DatagramSocket(60000);
            s.setSoTimeout(0);
        } else {
            s.receive(p);  
            ... 
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I guess it's a power-management-related problem on Android devices. I have tried place **PowerManager.WakeLock.aquire()** and **release()** before and after the while loop but that does take effect.

To be clear, this app is built for specific clients and does not care about how much battery it will drain(probably the only running app on device in most times lol).

Any idea what should I do? Should I choose **IntentService** or something like that to achieve this "infinite" UPD port listening work? I have spent a whole weekend seeking solutions in Android docs, but non of the examples said I could do a instantaneously triggered UDP socket listening[sad face].

For more information, I logged all three socket connection threads started in my service and find out that the one thread which uses tcp socket to send sth to server and wait for sth sent back works quite fine...

Comment: Use a foreground service

Comment: thanks! Would you like to be more specific? In fact, it is a foreground service since I have published a notification. I logged three connection threads in my service and found one thread using tcp port works correctly while this one just not.

Comment: For those who ran into similar problems: Engineers from Google blocks all broadcast-ed UDP packets in network related drivers executed under system level when screen goes off. I was trying receiving broadcast UDP packets and lost them all. Then I found an UDP packet with fixed address was received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We develop a SIP application with comparable requirements.

There is one important setting, your users have to take on their device, you can not do this in the app.

They need to go to Settings -> Data -> Background data and turn on "unlimited background data".
Also they should put the app to "not optimized" for battery optimization, so Android will not kill it/put it to sleep if it keeps draining the battery.
These are settings, an app simply can not do. it MUST be done by the user.

An in addition, you were quite right, a Wakelock for CPU only (i.e. without the `TURN_SCREEN_ON` flag) is the way to go.

But you should avoid having a wakelock open "forever", as android might kill this.

I would do something like this:

- 1. Aquire a wakelock "1" with timeout 30 seconds
- 2. After 25 seconds aquire a wakelock "2" and let "1" run out.
- 3. After another 30 seconds aquire "1" again and let "2" time out.
- 4. Back to step 2.

This is a background thread will will re-aquire another wakelock before the first wakelock times out.

I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Frankly, I did not found a setting with name "unlimited background data" but otherwise I turned on/off everything likely to be related and I am using wifi to debug this. so I guess this might not affect. Now I am giving the "spin-wake-lock" a try, hope it works! Thanks!